# Webpack dev server writeToDisk giving different result from serving without writing to disk

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, single-spa

I'm currently developing an application (single-spa) which uses the output from a different webpack bundled application.

The problem is that, when using webpack-dev-server without the `writeToDisk` option, it works seamlessly. But, when the `writeToDisk` option is used, it causes a weird bug in my application.

I'm not asking about the bug here, it's only for context. I'm asking what are the differences between `writeToDisk` and memory webpack-dev-server and how can I inspect it?